# Why do we need <form/> when we have AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I just started to learn JavaScript, and in my projects I found that wherever a form is used AJAX could be used instead.

A simple example is:

```
<form id="demo_form" action="demo" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And ajax could be used like this:

```
$('#demo_form input[type="submit"]').click(function(){    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/demo",
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            username: $('#demo_form input[name="username"]').val()
        }
    });
});
```

And an advantage of ajax is that it could be asynchronous, and I found it really sweet since you can still do something else while waiting for the response from server, and can probably keep the current page and do not lose your input.(when I submit a form, I have to either transfer all inputs to the server and back to the interface all again and just lose them).

Since form is still used and popular nowadays, I guess there are some advantages of it that I do not know.

Comment: `<form>` not only has the functionality of a form, but also the _semantics_ because HTML is a semantic language. A `form` is better than a `div` nested within dozens of other `div`s.

Comment: I will disable all the JS while accessing your site. Than what? no sweet ajax

Comment: the `<form>` is used so that you can validate the user's input on the client before submitting it to the server. It's alot better use of resources to make sure that all fields are correct before the `form` submits data to the server

Comment: @Bsienn fair enough but do that and I bet you'll find that the Ajax not working is the least of your issues...\

Comment: @SuperVeetz validating inputs is just as easily done with ajax as it is with a `form` element

Answer (score 20):

First and foremost, **the `<form>` element predates Ajax calls by years**. Ajax calls (it's better if you call them `XMLHttpRequest`) were an addition in Internet Explorer to make it possible to load/post data from JavaScript.

Perhaps most importantly, if you'd stop support either `<form>` elements *or* `XMLHttpRequest`, you'd **break basically all existing websites**.

Besides the requirement that you need to use JavaScript to issue `XMLHttpRequest` calls (with JavaScript not always being available), there's also functional and semantic differences:

- **HTML forms semantically group input elements** (otherwise, how would
  you know which input elements belong together?)
- They support some features
  like **file uploads** which until very recently weren't supported in
  JavaScript at all (you couldn't read the contents of files in file upload
  fields)
- Forms know how to **serialize input fields** (JavaScript libraries like jQuery reimplement this logic that comes for free with the browser)
- Forms **aren't affected by [CORS restrictions](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol)** (i.e. they
  can post to *any* server; whereas `XMLHttpRequest` requires special server-side configuration for this)
- Forms have **built-in user interface affordances** like submitting on pressing the enter/return key.
- Forms can **post data in different character sets and encodings** (via the `accept-charset` attribute), which is
  exceedingly difficult to do in JavaScript (in JavaScript all strings are Unicode)

`XMLHttpRequest` of course can do things that forms can't, for example set HTTP headers, can use more HTTP verbs (not only `post` and `get`), as you mentioned can be asynchronous and they also have a hugely expanded range of events you can react to.

Both technologies have their place, depending on what you'd like to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There's the case of providing functionality for users when JavaScript is not available. That and also realizing that some actions that we proxy over JavaScript like `PUT` and `DELETE` can't be done using `<form>` without proxying a hidden input like `<input type=hidden name=_method>`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a one major advantage that nobody mentioned so far - dynamic data population. Having only one field in the form, you wouldn't probably feel that.

But consider a form, that has several fields:

```
<input type="text" name="qty" />
<input type="text" name="price" />
<input type="text" name="title" />
... and so on ...
```

And you would populate data this way:

```
data : {
  price : $("[name='price']").val(),
  qty : $("[name='qty']").val(),
  title : $("[name='title']").val(),
}
```

And what If decide to add more fields later? You'd have append new field names with their values to `data`. And as your code grows, it would get messy quite fast.

Instead, you'd better stick to form serialization. The above can be simply rewritten as:

```
data : $("form").serialize()
```

And even if you add more fields later, you don't have to populate `data` anymore. In simple words, `$("form").serialize()` makes population of `data` dynamically.

Comment: You could always do `$( "#test" ).wrap( "<form></form>" ).parent().serialize()`

Comment: @DelightedD0D that's just an ugly hack to me

Comment: ok, consider `$('#myForm').append(someImputElement); $('#myForm').submit();` My point is just to illustrate that "dynamic data population" is not really an advantage of ajax in this sense, you can add fields to a form in many ways with or without ajax or vice versa. If anything, your answer demonstrates an advantage of using ajax **and** a form in conjunction with one another.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be better explained by someone with much more experience, but I'll give it a try:

Forms were created as part of HTML, as a way to send information from the browser to a server URL (the action attribute) waiting to do something with that information. Then, as part of JavaScript, it was created dynamic calls to the server (Asynchronous calls to be more specific). Those are probably more known today, but before it forms with actions were the way to solve that use case.

Comment: +1 definitely this. Forms preceded things like AJAX and were the de-facto means of sending client responses from a Web page back to the server.